# Can the length of current Unix timestamp greater then 10 Digits

Tags: php, laravel, unique, laravel-6

My Question Is :

Is The `time()` [10 Digits Number (Seconds)] can Be Increased to 11 or 12 digits ?

The Purpose of Asking This Question is I am creating A uniq transaction id depending on that and with some other variable.. I have to maintain a Length of 18 Digits (Numbers only)

Edit : 
Note I dont want to make it longer.. As it increases to 11/12 digits i have to make the rest 7/8 digits dynamically .. Because i am using 2 randomiser for that last 7/8 digits

Edit2:
Will it make sense => `rand(8 Digits)` vs `rand(3)` + `rand(3)` + `rand(2)` For Collision Purpose ??

Comment: _...can Be Increased to 11 or 12 digits ...._ Of course it will increase...but in many many many years in the future - **Note**  `time()` returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Comment: @B001ᛦ Yes that is what i want to know cause if it increases to 11/12 i have to maintain the rest 8/7 digits dynamically

Comment: Yes, in Saturday, 20 November 2286 y., 17:46:40 GMT

Comment: Thanks! Please see the Edit 2

Comment: I find your expected output to be Unclear. Is this an XY Problem?

Comment: @mickmackusa i did't get it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run `date()` with a time parameter containing the first 11 digit time you will see that you will not get 11 digits in a `time()` until

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', 10000000000);
```

RESULT

```
20/11/2286 17:46:40
```

If you think that your App will be running after that date you should worry about this situation, otherwise you dont need to worry or code for it.

PS I doubt PHP will exist or Intel come to that in 2286 :)

Comment: Hey I want to know another thing that if i use two 4 digits randomiser against 1 8 digit randomiser.. Will it be better for uniqness or it makes no sense ?? I dont know the logic properly

Comment: You are likely to get less duplicates with an 8 char random number than with a 4 char. But you may still get duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You do not have control over the function `time()`, it admits no parameters.
If you need to make it longer, you could prepend one or two 0 to the timestamp.

Comment: I dont want to make it longer ! As if it increases to 11/12 i have to make athe rest 8/7 digits dynamically